# to extract last value before a / in SQL

Tags: sql, charindex

I have this scenario where I have to extract the values in a column of URLs
[Given this is my column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQdHF.png)

and I'm expecting this in return. I want all the values before Question/ to be cut off in SQL
[this is my expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC5t6.png)
Tried this

```
right([URL], charindex('/', reverse([URL])) - 1)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In some scenarios you want to bring back text before and after the back slash and other times just the last text in the URL?

Comment: what is the SQL vendor you are using? Also, please don't link to images. Rather, post the code. We're spending time helping you for free. This will make it easier for us to copy / paste your examples and let other people find this on google and thus benefit from your question.

Comment: Right., charindex and reverse are all product specific functions. Which dbms are you using?